# combining MSB and LSB in short

Tags: c

I have a function that return `1 Byte`

```
uint8_t fun();
```

the function  should run 9 times , so I get 9 Byte I want to make the last`8` one as `4 short values` here what I've done but I'm not sure that the value that I get are correct  :

```
char array[9];
.............

for ( i = 0; i< 9 ; i++){
array[i] = fun();

}

printf( " 1. Byte %x  a = %d , b=%d c =%d \n" ,
    array[0],   
            *(short*)&(array[1]),
            *(short*)&(array[3]),
            *(short*)&(array[5]),
            *(short*)&(array[7]));
```

is that right ?

Comment: Result will depend if this runs on a big endian machine or not

Comment: @BillLynch That looks like a proper loop for 0 to 8 (inclusive) to me ...

Comment: @unwind It does after the edit :)

Comment: @beaker Ah, didn't see that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to be explicit and join the 8-bit values into 16-bit values yourself:

```
uint8_t  bytes[9];
uint16_t words[4];

words[0] = bytes[1] | (bytes[2] << 8);
words[1] = bytes[3] | (bytes[4] << 8);
words[2] = bytes[5] | (bytes[6] << 8);
words[3] = bytes[7] | (bytes[8] << 8);
```

The above assumes little-endian, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You will get alignement problems. Any pointer to a short can be seen as a pointer to char, but on non 8 bit machines, the inverse is not guaranteed.

IMHO, this would be safer :

```
struct {
    char arr0;
    union {
        char array[8];
        uint16_t sarr[4];
    } u;
} s;

s.arr0 = fun();
for ( i = 0; i< 8 ; i++){
    s.u.array[i] = fun();
}

printf( " 1. Byte %x  a = %d , b=%d c =%d d=%d\n" ,
    s.arr0,   
            s.u.sarr[0],
            s.u.sarr[1],
            s.u.sarr[2],
            s.u.sarr[3]);
```

But I suppose you deal correctly with endianness on your machine and know how the conversion 2 chars <=> 1 short works ...

Answer (score 0):

Try using `struct` to arrange the data and shift operations to convert for enianism.

```
// The existence of this function is assumed from the question.
extern unsigned char fun(void);

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char Byte;
    short WordA;
    short WordB;
    short WordC;
    short WordD;
}   converted_data;

void ConvertByteArray(converted_data* Dest, unsigned char* Source)
{
    Dest->Byte = Source[0];
    // The following assume that the Source bytes are MSB first.
    // If they are LSB first, you will need to swap the indeces.
    Dest->WordA = (((short)Source[1]) << 8) + Source[2];
    Dest->WordB = (((short)Source[3]) << 8) + Source[4];
    Dest->WordC = (((short)Source[5]) << 8) + Source[6];
    Dest->WordD = (((hshort)Source[7]) << 8) + Source[8];
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char array[9];
    converted_data convertedData;

    // Fill the array as per the question.    
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i< 9 ; i++)
    {
        array[i] = fun();
    }

    // Perform the conversion
    ConvertByteArray(&convertedData, array);

    // Note the use of %h not %d to specify a short in the printf!
    printf( " 1. Byte %x  a = %h , b=%h c =%h d =%h\n",
        (int)convertedData.Byte,  // Cast as int because %x assumes an int.
        convertedData.WordA,
        convertedData.WordB,
        convertedData.WordC,
        convertedData.WordD );

   return 0;
}
```